# Replace text in docx document

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, openxml, docx

I'm using `OpenXml` to replace text in `docx` document via my C# code. For this reason I'm using `SearchAndReplace` method from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-search-and-replace-text-in-a-document-part Here the method code is:

```
// To search and replace content in a document part.
public static void SearchAndReplace(string document)
{
    using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(document, true))
    {
        string docText = null;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
        {
            docText = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        Regex regexText = new Regex("{{Number}}");
        docText = regexText.Replace(docText, "12345");

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
        {
            sw.Write(docText);
        }
    }
}
```

During the test phase I noticed that mentioned code sometimes works correctly and sometimes it doesn't. After deaper investigation I discovered that the reason is on internal structure of `docx` document. For instance I have two `docx` documents, in both there is `{{Number}}` text. Even more, the documents looks totally identical if opened through MS Office Word. But the the way how text is stored internally on `document.xml` is different. Here are the corresponding fragments of `document.xml` for both `docx` documents:

`document.xml` for `MyWordDoc1.docx`:

```
<w:p w14:paraId="0C2491BB" w14:textId="56E92F22" w:rsidR="001C522D" w:rsidRDefault="00D570B1">
    <w:r>
        <w:t>{{</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r w:rsidR="00B908ED">
        <w:t>Number</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
        <w:t>}}</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
```

and `document.xml` for `MyWordDoc2.docx`:

```
<w:p w14:paraId="099057D3" w14:textId="56FD88C8" w:rsidR="00465234" w:rsidRDefault="00773DCC">
    <w:r>
        <w:t>{{Number}}</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
```

So as you can see for `MyWordDoc1.docx` `{{Number}}` text is divided into separate parts.

Can anybody explain how to verify on `document.xml` that few text parts are the parts of the same word on `docx` document and how to update mentioned C# method to ensure replace operation works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform string operations on text in a Word document, you cannot assume that your search string will be found in `Text` element. In general, there are `Paragraphs` which contain many `Run` which contain many `Text` elements. For your case I would iterate through all `Text` under a run, concatenate them, perform the replace, and finally replace the existing `Text` elements with my new `Text` element.

```
using WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open("number.docx", true);

var body = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;

var paraElems = body.Elements<Paragraph>();

foreach (var paraElem in paraElems)
{
    foreach (var runElem in paraElem.Elements<Run>())
    {
        string allText = string.Empty;
        foreach (var textElem in runElem.Elements<Text>())
        {
            allText += textElem.Text;
            textElem.Remove();
        }

        //replace text
        if (allText.Contains("{{number}}"))
        {
            allText = allText.Replace("{{number}}", "ta daa!");
        }

        var newText = new Text()
        {
            Text = allText
        };
        
        runElem.Append(newText);
    }
}
```

In replacing strings, one should think if concatenating `Text` elements is enough or does one needs to concatenate `Run` elements as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a library ([DocxTemplater](https://github.com/Amberg/DocxTemplater)) that replaces patterns like `{{placeholder}}` with some data.

The library builds a lookup table for each character position for the corresponding text node. The search can then take place over the complete text (all strings appended together). After a match, the corresponding text nodes can then be queried via the index. The individual text nodes are then merged together, whereby the first one with the formatting is retained

You can find an example of such a looup here here: [CharacterMap](https://github.com/Amberg/DocxTemplater/blob/main/DocxTemplater/CharacterMap.cs)

And the method to join the text nodes here: [MergeText](https://github.com/Amberg/DocxTemplater/blob/70f27339e8b31eabded0476ea5bb09809ec946ff/DocxTemplater/OpenXmlHelper.cs#L174)

```
public static Text MergeText(this Text first, int startIndex, Text last, int length)
    {
        var commonParent = first.FindCommonParent(last) ?? throw new ArgumentException("Text elements must have a common parent");
        if (startIndex < 0 || startIndex >= first.Text.Length)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(startIndex));
        }
        var matchInSameElement = first == last;
        var firstTextLength = first.Text.Length;
        if (startIndex != 0) // leading text is not part of the match
        {
            first = first.SplitAtIndex(startIndex);
        }
        if (startIndex + length < firstTextLength) // trailing text part of the match in the first element
        {
            first.SplitAtIndex(length);
        }

        if (matchInSameElement)
        {
            return first;
        }

        List<OpenXmlElement> toRemove = new();
        bool found = false;
        foreach (var current in commonParent.Descendants<Text>())
        {
            if (current == first)
            {
                found = true;
                continue;
            }
            if (!found)
            {
                continue;
            }

            // trailing text is not part of the match int the last element
            if (first.Text.Length + current.Text.Length > length)
            {
                var firstPart = current.Text[..(length - first.Text.Length)];
                var secondPart = current.Text[(length - first.Text.Length)..];
                first.Text += firstPart;
                current.Text = secondPart;
                break;
            }
            first.Text += current.Text;
            toRemove.Add(current);
            if (current == last)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        foreach (var text in toRemove)
        {
            text.RemoveWithEmptyParent();
        }
        return first;
    }
```